# Gitlab : Redusse the size of .git folder without losing all git history

Tags: git, symfony

I have a **symfony** project that contain a folder named **.git**  with too big size : *up to 4.4 Gigabyte*

I khow that folder contain the history of the project.i whould like to find a way to reduise this size without lousing all project history.

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compact it and drop all the left over

```
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

This will remove all the un-merged content and will re-pack the pack and idx files

---

`git repack`
just repacks the objects. This will combine all the separated pack files into a single one and **might** reduce the size

`git gc`
repacks them and **also throws away** the old unreachable objects

Comment: so it looks like your repo is optimized. after you run it you should not see any objects under the git folder. `tree .git` should not display any files under object folder and you should have only single pack + idx files. If this is the case so your repo is optimized.

Comment: try to see if you have binaries files and if you do try to switch to gitLFs of use BFG - https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/